# How to hide timer in React Awesome Slider in autoplay

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider, carousel, autoplay

I am using React Awesome Slider with autoplay feature. But when I do that a timer appears on slide changes and wraps the slide item. Although I set `showtime: {false}`, it doesn't reflect correctly.

```
import AwesomeSlider from 'react-awesome-slider'
import withAutoplay from 'react-awesome-slider/dist/autoplay'

const AutoplaySlider = withAutoplay(AwesomeSlider)

const MySlider = () => (
  <AutoplaySlider play={true} showTimer={false}>
     <div>1</div>
     <div>2</div>
     <div>3</div>
  </AutoplaySlider>
)
```

Comment: You should create a minimal reproducible example (better on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any solution for this. It seems to be a bug regarding React Awesome Slider. I might send a pull request for this. However, I used CSS to enforce hide the timer.

```
.my-slider-class-name .awssld__timer {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none; /* prevent events (mouse clicking etc.) */
}
```

**NOTE:** When I tried display: none it, slider stopped working.